# Android: Actionbar menuitem icons for gridview and listview styles

Tags: android, icons, menuitem

Are there default icons for a menu item whose functionality is to change gridview to listview or vice versa. I know there are some icons like search, done, edit etc. I just couldn't find any for this purpose.

Comment: You can view all default icons in **sdk/platforms/api version/android.jar** just unzip it and you can see all the icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can view all default icons in sdk/platforms/apiversion/android.jar 
just unzip it and you can see all the icons
```

Depending on Muhammad's comment, there is no such icon in `sdk/platforms/api version/android.jar` on `API 21`.